# height of a N-ary tree

Tags: java, data-structures

I have tried to write a method called `getHeight()` to calculate the height of am N-ary tree. My attempt does not work. This is the tree interface I am using:

```
public interface MyTree  {
    Tree getSubTree(int i) ;//returns a subtree
    boolean isLeaf() ;//returns true if the node is a leaf
    int getDegree() ; 
}
```

This is the piece of code that I have written:

```
public int getHeight(){

    for(int i = 0 ; i<getDegree()-1 ; ++i){  

        if(isLeaf()){
            return 0; 

        }else{
            return 1 + Math.Max(getSubtree(i).getHeight() , getSubtree(i+1).getHeight() ; 
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this method?

Comment: why are you mixing recursion and for loops?

Comment: well , when you have an exam on data structure within 16 hours . you do these kind of stupid things...

Comment: @user2573153 I can't speak for OP, but I too would iterate over the children of a node and recur into each child. Simply because iteration is easier than recursion for the first and recursion is easier than iteration for the second. That part is fine.

Answer (score 5):

Your issue is here:

```
 return 1 + getSubtree(i).getHeight();
```

you are returning from the method as soon as you calculate 1 + the height of a single sub tree. What you actually need to do is call `getHeight()` on EVERY subtree, and return 1 + the maximum of each of those. (This could be simplified if your tree has any balance properties.)

For example, if the tree you are calling this on has three subtrees, with heights 2, 4, and 5, you code will call `getHeight()` on the first subtree and see 2, then immediately return 3, instead of checking `getHeight()` on the remaining subtrees to find that there is a taller subtree  (the one with height 5).